# How to Reverse Proxy using Nginx to Dockerized Swagger UI's along with web apis?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, swagger-ui

I have 2 servers, one with dockerized nginx and one with 3 dockerized web apis allowing traffic through different ports (say 441, 442, 443) which has swagger UI along with it respectively.

with limited knowledge on nginx, I am trying to reverse proxy to all the swagger UI endpoints using the nginx container. This is how my nginx conf looks like, but it doesnt work as expected, it would be great if someone can advice where I am going wrong.

I am able to hit the service with the exact match location context /FileService which return index.html. But index.html has the script call where nginx fails to serve these static contents.

**index.html**

```
<script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
<script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.webby.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/yyyy.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xxxx.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    if ($http_referer = 'https://$host/FileService') {
        rewrite ^/(\w+) /swagger/fileservice/$1;
    }
    if ($http_referer = 'https://$host/PreProcess') {
        rewrite ^/(\w+) /swagger/preprocess/$1;
    }

    location = /FileService {
        proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:441/swagger/index.html';
    }

    location = /PreProcess {
        proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:442/swagger/index.html';
    }
    
    # curl http://appy.com:441/swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js is giving the js on this container
    location ~* /swagger/fileservice(.*) {
        proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:441/swagger/$1';
    }

    location ~* /swagger/preprocess(.*) {
        proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:442/swagger/$1';
    }

}
```

accesslog on the nginx looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

anyways I struggled my way to implement this. Not sure if its the right approach (because I read on the internet that if block inside location context is evil), but works for my case. Feel free to correct my answer

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.webby.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/yyyy.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xxxx.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;


    location = /FileService {
        proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:441/swagger/index.html';
    }

    location = /PreProcess {
        proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:442/swagger/index.html';
    }
    
    location ~ ^/swagger/(.*)$ {
        if ($http_referer = 'https://$host/FileService') {
            proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:441/swagger/$1';
        }
        if ($http_referer = 'https://$host/PreProcess') {
            proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:442/swagger/$1';
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/swagger(.*)$ {
        if ($http_referer = 'https://$host/FileService') {
            proxy_pass 'http://appy.com:441/swagger/swagger$1';
        }
        if ($http_referer = 'https://$host/PreProcess') {
            proxy_pass 'hhttp://appy.com:442/swagger/swagger$1';
        }          
    }
}
```